# history.push() and <Redirect /> not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I've tried about 5-7 different solutions regarding redirects and histories not working on react-router.
This is create-react-app code:

**index.js**

```js
import { Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './History';
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**History.jsx**

```js
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**SplashScreen.jsx**

```js
return (
  <ViewContext.Provider value={this.state.contextChangeUtils}>
    <WrappedComponent/>
  </ViewContext.Provider>
);
```

**App.jsx**

```js
static propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
//...
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: MainPage,
}, {
  path: '/status-history',
  component: HistoryPage,
}, {
  path: '/status-details',
  component: DetailsPage
}]

if (this.context.viewInfo.path!==this.state.lastPath) {
  this.setState({lastPath: this.context.viewInfo.path});
  let { history } = this.props;
  history.push(this.context.viewInfo.path);
}

return (
  <Container className="App pl-0 pr-0">
    <StatusHeader />
    <Row>
      <Col md="1" />
      <Col md="2" className="TagListOuter">
        <TagList tags={tags} />
      </Col>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(r => (
          <Route path={r.path} key={r.path} component={r.component} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);

App.contextType = ViewContext;

export default SplashScreen(withRouter(App));
```

- I have tried using this.props.history.push() inside the components on each route
- I have tried using a simple  at all levels of my application (even index.js)

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "Your  path",
        state: {
          lastPath: this.context.viewInfo.path
        }
});
```

and you can get data using `this.props.location.state` or `this.props.location.state.lastPath`

Answer (score 0):

If you created a custom history instance to manage your react router histories and calling function, so use it as below instead of importing **withRouter** and injecting it to the component.

```js
import history from "../History.js"

static propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
//...
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: MainPage,
}, {
  path: '/status-history',
  component: HistoryPage,
}, {
  path: '/status-details',
  component: DetailsPage
}]

if (this.context.viewInfo.path!==this.state.lastPath) {
  this.setState({lastPath: this.context.viewInfo.path});

  history.push(this.context.viewInfo.path);
}

return (
  <Container className="App pl-0 pr-0">
    <StatusHeader />
    <Row>
      <Col md="1" />
      <Col md="2" className="TagListOuter">
        <TagList tags={tags} />
      </Col>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(r => (
          <Route path={r.path} key={r.path} component={r.component} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);

App.contextType = ViewContext;

export default SplashScreen(App);
```